# Row_number() in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a query:

```
select .....
from....
order by ....
```

I would like to add row numbers to this query.

When I read about `row_number()` it says that the syntax is:

```
row_number() OVER(ORDER BY ...)
```

meaning I have to do:

```
select row_number() OVER(ORDER BY ...) , .....
from....
order by ....
```

That means that I have to write twice the same `ORDER BY` statement.

Is there a way to just do something like:

```
select row_number() , .....
from....
order by ....
```

meaning that it will take whatever order that was given from the query and simply add numbers to it.

Comment: No, that's not possible. The sort order used in the window function does not necessarily have to be the same as the overall sort order

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't have a postgresql here, but he could try simply by ordering on the generated `row_number()` (if it is like SQL Server, the ORDER BY phase is AFTER the SELECT phase, so he can give an alias to the generated `row_number()` and then order on it)

Comment: @xanatos: ah, right that would work.

Comment: You mean do drop order by from query, do it as `select row_number() OVER(ORDER BY ...)  as rownum`, and then `order by rownum`?

Comment: @java Yep, exactly like that. Sadly SQL Fiddle isn't working now, so I can't test it.

Comment: Right, something like: `select row_number() over (order by ..) as rn, .... from ... order by rn`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Postgres does allow the syntax:

```
select row_number() over (), . . .
```

However, that does not necessary return the row numbers in the ordering specified by the outer `order by`.  I think Postgres calculates the row number before the order by.

You might be tempted to use:

```
select row_number() over (), . . .
from (select . . . 
      from . . .
      order by  . . .
     ) t;
```

And, this would seem to do what you want (one a single processor machine, for instance, it just did the right thing).  However, this is not guaranteed to work.  The ordering in a subquery does not apply to the outer query (although this might only be visible on multi-processor machines).

My advice?  Simply repeat the `order by` twice (using either the expression or the alias).  That is guaranteed to work.  And, you might be surprised at the optimizer only needing to sort the data once.

Comment: As mentioned by xanatos, `select row_number() over (order by ..) as rn, .... from ... order by rn` would work in Postgres

Comment: Longshot, but does anyone have any idea on how this would be done using typeorm?